Question on a vector inequality
Is it true that
$$
\min\left( \begin{aligned}
&\|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\| - \|\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}\|, \\
&\|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{w}\| - \|\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{w}\|, \\
&\|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{x}\| - \|\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{x}\|, \\
&\|\mathbf{v}\| + \|\mathbf{w}\| - \|\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}\|, \\
&\|\mathbf{v}\| + \|\mathbf{x}\| - \|\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{x}\|, \\
&\|\mathbf{w}\| + \|\mathbf{x}\| - \|\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{x}\|
\end{aligned} \right) \leq \frac{3}{20}
$$
for all $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|\mathbf{u}\| + \|\mathbf{v}\| + \|\mathbf{w}\| + \|\mathbf{x}\| = 1$?
Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

If you give the source of this expression it could possibly be better (otherwise the effort to give an answer may consist for 80% of going back to your starting point. This usually happens here).

@PietroMajer  It was revised. Thanks.

I have done many computations and have not found any counterexamples.

@PietroMajer  Hello, what if describing the question in the original language seems more complex, and one needs to find a solution that is clear or concise? Thanks.

For instance, this is now more geometrically clear than the previous one in coordinates  (as a very starting point for a solution, I would have first of all  transformed the problem to the present formulation)   (Of course if the  question is complex one should try to simplify it, e.g. removing useless constants.  The guidelines for posting questions give good  hints )

I would assume  that the maximal possible value of the $\min$ is $1/2-1/\sqrt8$, attained on $\pm \frac14 e_1$, $\pm \frac14 e_2$. Is there any counterexample to this?

@IlyaBogdanov if there is something wrong with my answer claiming to prove this bound, would you please specify what?

@FedorPetrovNo, sorry; the only trouble was that, when I made my commeny, I did not notice your answer...

The sharp constant is $\theta:=(2-\sqrt{2})/4<3/20$, so the answer is positive. An example when the minimum equals $\theta$ is provided by 4 vectors of length $1/4$ and distinct horizontal/vertical directions.
Assume that all these expressions exceed $\theta$. Draw the vectors from the origin, there are 4 angles between consecutive vectors (one of these angles may exceed $\pi$), which sum up to $2\pi$. Choose two opposite angles with sum not exceeding $\pi$, without loss of generality, these are the angles $2\alpha$ between $u$ and $v$ and $2\beta$ between $w$ and $x$, $\alpha+\beta\leqslant \pi/2$. We have \begin{align*}\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2\|u\|\cdot \|v\|\cos 2\alpha=(\|u\|+\|v\|)^2-2\|u\|\cdot \|v\|(1-\cos 2\alpha) \\
\geqslant (\|u\|+\|v\|)^2-\frac{(\|u\|+\|v\|)^2}2(1-\cos2\alpha)=(\|u\|+\|v\|)^2\cos^2\alpha,\end{align*}
thus $\|u+v\|\geqslant (\|u\|+\|v\|)\cos \alpha$ and $$\theta<\|u\|+\|v\|-\|u+v\|\leqslant (\|u\|+\|v\|)(1-\cos\alpha),$$
analogously, $\theta<(\|w\|+\|x\|)(1-\cos \beta)$. This yields that $\alpha$, $\beta$ are strictly positive and $$
\frac1{1-\cos \alpha}+\frac1{1-\cos \beta}< \theta^{-1}(\|u\|+\|v\|)
+\theta^{-1}(\|w\|+\|x\|)=\theta^{-1}.$$
On the other hand, $f(x):=1/(1-\cos x)$ is a convex function on $(0,\pi/2)$
(indeed, $$f'(x)=\frac{-\sin x}{(1-\cos x)^2}=\frac{-2\sin \frac{x}2\cos \frac{x}2}{4\sin^4\frac{x}2}=-\frac12\frac{\cos \frac x2}{\sin^3\frac{x}2}$$
that increases on $(0,\pi/2)$ because $\sin x/2$ increases and $\cos x/2$ decreases.) Therefore, by Jensen inequality we have
$$
\frac1{1-\cos \alpha}+\frac1{1-\cos \beta}\geqslant \frac2{1-\cos \frac{\alpha+\beta}2}\geqslant \frac2{1-\cos\pi/4}=\theta^{-1},
$$
a contradiction.
